# Weird character needed to end a TCP/IP stream cant figure out what it is

Tags: php, tcp, ascii, fsockopen

Im connecting to a DMX controller using fsockopen. (Or even telnet via putty)#

And it sends the following CHAR at the end of a command. I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is...
Their documentation doesnt say annoyingly and i need to use it as the "end of stream" as the return byte count varies.

Putty shows : ▒

Web browser shows as : ?

Hex editor shows as (FF) ÿ

What one earth could it be?

My code:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("localhost", "3333");
fputs($fp,"FSBC017000");
$content = stream_get_line($fp, 10000, "**<Whatever that char is?>**");
echo $content;
?>
```

Thanks to anyone in advance. Brain is broken.

Comment: Such sadness. much pain.  ANy idea how to just set a timeout for returned data? Say.. after 2 seconds.. assume the data recieved is full, close connection and use the data recieved?